# Why perfmon for remote desktop servers get an empty file (only time stamp)?

Tags: performance, monitoring, windows, remote-desktop-services, perfmon

I'm trying to remotely monitor a server using perfmon, the output file is always empty and only the time stamp field is there?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to check the basic settings that may not allow the 'Perfmon' to fetch the details on the remote machine. Please take a look at the below suggestion and ensure it is all fine.

1. Turn of AV and Local firewall, to check if the 'Perfmon' collects the value
2. Take a network trace with the help some third party tool and see what's going on
3. Disable UAC and check
4. Check whether you are you able to connect to WMI on the remote machine
5. Check whether the Perfmon process started with the administrator privilege
6. Also, perform a net use \machine name\admin$ and see you are able to browse any shares such as the printer folder, etc.

Hope this helps.